# Render view after user login validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to render a view after a login validation form has created a session after successful credentials have been entered.

This view must **only** be accessible after the login procedure, but when I type in the url (127.0.0.1:3000/newsfeed) the 'newsfeed' page is loaded and bypasses the login. I understand that this could be an issue related to routes but I can not get it to work.

```
//session
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/'));
});

// Checking credentials
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.password;
if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password 
= ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect('authres');
        } else {
            response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }
        response.end();
    });
} else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
}
});

//**Would like page to appear here instead of text**
app.get('/authres', function(request, response) {
if (request.session.loggedin) {
    response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');


} else {
    response.send('Please login to view this page!');
}
response.end();
});
```

Methods in app.js

```
//uses routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/newsfeed', newsfeedRouter);
```

index.js route for the log in

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index');
});
```

newsfeed.js route for newsfeed page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('newsfeed');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render(req.session.loggedin?"newsfeed":"index");
});
```

If the user is logged in this will render the newsfeed view.

Comment: Works, thanks! Just made a small adjustment. Instead of router.get, I made it app.get.

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render(req.session.loggedin?"newsfeed":"index");
    });